# i want to display a success image after filling up each text fields or selecting the categories using ajax or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

Here is what i have done ..i want to display the image after input fields is fill up the first field is working now  how to add extra input fields to display that particular image on that input fields suggestion are welcome..... 
HTML CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#username").blur(function() { // when focus out

        //$("#message").html(''); //before AJAX response

        var form_data = {
            action: 'last_name',
            username: $(this).val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#lastnamefirstname").html(result);   
            }
        });

    });


});


<div id="lastnamefirstname"></div>
 <input id="username" name="lname" required="required" class="text"  placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

functions.php

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'last_name')
    {
        $firstnamelast = $_POST['username'];
        if($firstnamelast!='')
        {
        last_name($firstnamelast);
        }
    }

    function last_name($firstnamelast)
    {   
        echo ' <img src="images/profile/name.png" style="margin: 1px 0 -28px -37px;"/>';
    }
```

Comment: define dataType : 'html' in $.ajax call...i have tested it and its working bro..have you checked in firebug for possible errors or warnings..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following if statement. It just checks if all input fields are not empty.

```
if ( ($("#field_id_1").val() != '') && ($("#field_id_2").val() != '') && ... ) {
  // display image
  // trigger ajax request

}
```

The idea with the blur is not the most appropriate since the field can be left empty if something else is focused.